# django 404 error when running a server on window 10 with python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am getting an error in my `django` project.

The `/api` and `/admin` urls are working fine, its only the main page that throws this error:

> Using the `URLconf` defined in `backend.urls`, `Django` tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> `api-auth/`
>
> `admin/`
>
> `api/`
>
> The empty path didn't match any of these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you have `DEBUG = True` in your `Django`
>   settings file. Change that to False, and `Django` will display a
>   standard 404 page.

My **urls.py** file is as follow

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/',include('movies.api.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Well, you don't seem to have defined a path for the "main page". What makes you think you have?

Comment: yeah my bad but what can I define for a empty path doesn't django have a page for a empty string or do i have to define myself?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the regex for the empty request ( Homepage)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,re_path, include

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^', include('app_name.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/',include('movies.api.urls'))
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined a URL for your start page.

1. You need to define a view for your start page (maybe you already have one?), or use a default view like `TemplateView` or something similar.
2. you need to add a new URL to your patterns for that start page view; probably similar to this:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       path('', views.start_page, name='start_page'),

       path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('api/',include('movies.api.urls'))
   ]
   ```